# How to get the redshift snapshots with terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Terraform provides data sources to get the snapshots for RDS using aws_db_cluster_snapshot and aws_db_snapshot.
How can I get the cluster snapshots for a redshift cluster in terraform?
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: I'd like an answer for this too. There doesn't appear to be a data resource for redshift snapshots

Answer (score 0):

You can't (yet).

My work around is to run:

`aws redshift describe-cluster-snapshots --cluster-identifier ${cluster_identifier} --max-items 1 --query 'Snapshots[0].SnapshotIdentifier'  --region ${aws_region}`

As we run Terraform on Jenkins it's a reasonable work around. Alternatively you could run similar as a null_resource provisioner, output the result to a file, then use terraform to read that file

```
resource "null_resource" "redshift_snap" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = "create"
    command = "aws redshift describe-cluster-snapshots --cluster-identifier ${var.cluster_identifier} --max-items 1 --query 'Snapshots[0].SnapshotIdentifier'  --region ${var.region} > snapshot_identifier.txt"
  }
}
```

`snapshot_identifier = file("${path.module}/snapshot_identifier.txt")`

I know it's a bit dirty, but should work until Terraform release a data for Redshift snaps.